# Kiosk app updates when device not online at consistent times

Tags: android-management-api

**Background**

I currently maintain a Kiosk app on devices managed by the Android Management API. These devices run Android 7.

I had been managing the app updates on these devices via the application `minimumVersionCode`, and moving the devices onto a new policy every time with a higher `minimumVersionCode`, forcing the affected devices to update the app. However some of the devices would factory reset if they had been off for a reasonable period of time (a week or two) even after extending the wipeDays to 300 etc (I've reported a bug separately for this).

So, I need to work around the above bug, and I guess moving devices en-masse between policies isn't a well tested or the perceived "correct" way to do this. I see the recommended configuration for managing kiosks using the API has been stealthily changed in the last 6-9 months (according to archive.org .. nothing in the API changelog). There is now an `applications.[x].installType` of 'KIOSK'.

**Question**

I've got around 250 kiosks that have varied on/off times. Some will turn on at 8am and will be turned off at 3pm. Others will turn on at say 6pm and will turn off at midnight. Others will stay on all the time (although note that I do have the ability to remotely reboot them via the Android Management API).

So WRT updating the kiosk app, there isn't a neat tight maintenance window of 2-3am that I can configure.

Will specifying a maintenance window of "all day" get around this? E.g:

```
{

...

  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.something",
      "installType": "KIOSK",
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
      "minimumVersionCode": 30
    }
  ],

...

  "systemUpdate": {
    "type": "WINDOWED",
    "startMinutes": 0,
    "endMinutes": 1439
  },

...

}
```

I'm worried that the above won't work (or more correctly, will work intermittently), if the API just randomises a time when the particular device is never powered on.

I'm just wondering how to manage this problem. Should I just have one policy for all devices, and increment the version code?

Comment: Unless I otherwise see a better idea, I'm going back to my old way of doing things (moving between policies) as the WINDOWED mode doesn't seem to work for me.

But I'm going to change things so the policy for a device only gets changed when a device comes online (as otherwise when the device comes online next time it intermittently resets).

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up, my previously suggested approach of only changing policies when the device is currently online (and has been online for 5 minutes) is working well. Yay.

Devices are no longer factory resetting themselves if they've been offline for a period of time. It seems to be the combination of a policy change while the device has been offline that's the problem, presumably also due to the fact that the software update isn't instantaneous.